# Java 8 filter List of Map objects based on Map property to remove some duplicates

Tags: java, java-8

Have a

```
List<Map<String, Object>> allPoints = new LinkedList<>();
```

Each map contains a `"name"` key with a String value;
Need to create a

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> expectedPoints
```

There are duplicate names in the list; for these, want to keep the last one only.

E.g. if the list has three items, and first and third items both have"name" with value "abc", the resulting list should only contain the second and third items from the original list.

Comment: so you just want the unique keys? no duplicates?

Comment: didnt understand anything from this questions. please add more info and show examples

Comment: Please provide some example of what you are trying to do. Question is not very clear.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but how the set will be populated such that only last duplicate one is put in set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is by using an auxiliary map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(allPoints.size(), 0.75f, true);
allPoints.forEach(point -> map.put((String)point.get("name"), point));

List<Map<String, Object>> expectedPoints = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

This works because `Map.put` either puts a new entry to the map or overwrites the value of an existing entry with the new one, thus keeping only the last point associated with the name.

I'm creating an *access-ordered* `LinkedHashMap` by using its [overloaded constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-). This is to maintain the same order as in the `allPoints` list.

Comment: Works fine... But did you read the last sentence the OP wrote? I think the question is messy.

Comment: ArrayList(map.values()). You are missing diamond operator there.

Comment: This maintains the insertion order based on the first time the key is seen, though. For the example where items 1 and 3 have the same name, this would return a list with the 3rd item first.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner `LinkedHashMap` takes as input the number of *buckets* as argument, not *elements* (`CHM` does elements), so better to say `allPoints.size() / 0.75 + 1`

Comment: @Eugene I know, thanks for your feedback. But I didn't want to complicate the constructor further. Besides, the size of the map will be lower than the size of the list, due to duplicates. So, I don't expect the map to be resized more than one time.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have the constraint on one or more key-value pairs and flexible to use a Set, write your own Comparator and use `descendingIterator` on `LinkedList` and write to `TreeSet`. See code below:

```
        LinkedList<Map<String, Object>> allPoints = new LinkedList<>();

        Set<Map<String, Object>> expectedPoints = new TreeSet<>((objectMap1, objectMap2) ->
                objectMap2.get("name").equals(objectMap1.get("name")) ? 0 : -1
        );

        allPoints.descendingIterator().forEachRemaining(expectedPoints::add);
```

Comment: what happens if I replace -1 with 1 or other value? Good answer though...

Comment: the order in which items are shown would be altered.